# Why do some apps not show up on the dock in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, dock

I'm not sure if this was intentional, or if this is a problem, but when I open the App Store or Messages, they don't show up at all in the dock, but they run just fine otherwise. Why is this and how can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps to fix problems with the Dock:

- Run `killall Dock` from a terminal
- Log out and back in
- Reboot the machine
- Reinstall the apps affected
- Try to create a new user profile